# What is the package name of android.speech.RecognizerIntent?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intune, android-speech-api

I am using Google speech [recognizer intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent) in my application.
It is working well in a normal environment.

[image]

But this app is being developed for a managed environment Microsoft Intune.
As per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-protection-policies-exception#android-data-transfer-exceptions), I need to exempt the speech recognizer intent in Microsoft Intune app protection policy. Intune app protection policy is expecting the package name or identifier such as *com.android.browser* for the exemption.

I cannot find the correct package name for [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent) speech recognizer intent.
Is there any way to find the package id for this?
Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the package names of the components that will resolve the `Intent` by doing so:

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos){
    Log.d(TAG, "Package name resolving the intent:" + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
}
```